# As a Chemical Engineer, please tell me what is the rinsing temperature in steel pickling process and why is the rinse water heated

Tags: steel

I want to know what is the ideal temperature required for rinsing the steel sheet in steel pickling process and why is rinse water heated, why not water at room temperature or cold water used to clean the sheet

Comment: What research have you done towards this?

Comment: try washing greasy dishes in cold water and then try washing greasy dishes in hot water ... do you notice a difference?

Comment: @SolarMike Sir I am working on this and so I want to know what is the ideal temperature required for rinsing the steel sheet since it is not mentioned in any research paper

Comment: @jsotola does this mean the reaction will take place faster because of heating the rinse water